# Raspberry Pi + ownCloud: never stops finishing setup wizard

Tags: raspberry-pi, owncloud

**Model**: Raspberry Pi 3 model B+

**OS**: Raspbian Stretch

**Target disk for data storage**: Netgear readyNAS (NTFS, fstab mounted) with share for ownCloud and www-data as owner on mount

I've been following [this guide](https://www.avoiderrors.net/owncloud-10-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-stretch/) for installing and setting up ownCloud on my Pi. I've been following every step and doing exactly what the guide says.
It all goes well until the very last step where I fill out the forms for setting up ownCloud via the browser, seemingly correct inputs and no errors, and when i click the finish button it just loads forever. The browser also indicates that the page is loading and this goes on forever.

Tables in the ownCloud database on the Pi gets created so something is happening, but it never seems to create the admin user as the oc_users table is empty no matter how long I wait. The Pi also seems to slow down drastically when doing this as it takes forever to perform simple and otherwise instant tasks like ls, rmdir, rm, etc...

The target disk for data storage as filled in in the ownCloud wizard data directory path is a NAS disk mounted with www-data (uid/guid 33) as owner and chmoded with 777. I know for a fact that the www-data user has the right privileges to the disk since I've overcome permission issues before as well as the correct mysql credentials. Ive tried ownCloud version 10.0.3/8 and 9.1.8 with the same result.

Has anybody encountered this issue before or have any clue what this is all about?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just insanely slow..
Had it running for about 2 hours and it finally finished and prompted me to the login page where I was able to login and finally use my ownCloud. Installed a php cache optimizer and it seemed to have improved a bit.